# Find Homogeneous Differential Equation From Two Dynamic Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, homogeneous-equation

Equation #1
$$
y^{''}+C_1t^{''}+C_2y = C_3y^{'}+C_4t
$$
Equation #2
$$
C_5y^{''}+C_6t^{''}+C_7t = C_8y^{'}+C_9t
$$
Both y and t are dynamic, and I need to somehow get these two equations into homogeneous differential equations. It has been a while since I've taken Diff Eq, so I might be missing something obvious.I can't seem to remember how to do differential equations with 2 dynamic variables so I dont even know how to start.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but y is supposed to represent a change in height of a wing and t the pitch of a wing. If that helps it make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a homogeneous equation/system. It is, in matrix-vector form, of the type
$$
Mu''+Nu'+Ru=0
$$
$u=(y,t)^T$, and has to be transformed as
$$
u''+M^{-1}Nu'+M^{-1}Ru=0
$$
to get the system into explicit form.